# MvvmCross Custom Binding not notified by RaisePropertyChanged

Tags: c#, xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm trying to implement a triggerable animation on an `MvxImageView` (within an android CardView) to overlay a color (green or red) onto the image on the change of a property on the card's ViewModel. I have created the custom class DynamicImageView using Stuart Lodge's example [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/blob/master/N-33-AnimateTextChanges/TextChange.Droid/Controls/AnimatingTextView.cs).

```
public class DynamicImageView : MvxImageView
{
    public DynamicImageView(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public DynamicImageView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
    {
    }

    public DynamicImageView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
    {
    }

    protected DynamicImageView(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        Drawable d = this.Drawable;

        if (d != null)
        {
            // ceil not round - avoid thin vertical gaps along the left/right edges
            int width = MeasureSpec.GetSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            int height = (int)Math.Ceiling(width * (float)d.IntrinsicHeight / d.IntrinsicWidth);
            this.SetMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }

    private ObjectAnimator colorFilterAnimation;

    private string _animatingColor;
    public string AnimatingColor
    {
        set
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Animation triggered");
            if (value != _animatingColor)
            {
                _animatingColor = value;
                colorFilterAnimation = ObjectAnimator.OfObject((ImageView)this, "colorFilter", new ArgbEvaluator(), 0, 0);
                switch (value)
                {
                    case "red":
                        colorFilterAnimation.SetObjectValues(0, new Color(100, 0, 0, 80).ToArgb());
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Starting Red Animation");
                        break;
                    case "green":
                        colorFilterAnimation.SetObjectValues(0, (int)Color.Green);
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Starting Green Animation");
                        break;
                }
                colorFilterAnimation.SetDuration(1000);
                colorFilterAnimation.Start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Within the ViewModel for this control, I have the matching property defined as well, following standard MvvmCross notation:

```
private string _animatingColor;
    public string AnimatingColor {
        get
        {
            return _animatingColor;
        }
        set
        {
            _animatingColor = value;
            Debug.WriteLine("AnimatingColor set to " + value);
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => AnimatingColor);
        }
    }
```

This property is changed on a click to the card, and when I click I do see the Debug print from within the property `set`, but it doesn't seem to trigger the `set` for AnimatingColor within the control at all. The control is referenced in axml as normal:

```
<DynamicImageView
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:scaleType="centerCrop"
  local:MvxBind="ImageUrl 'http:'+Profile.Headshot.Url; AnimatingColor .AnimatingColor" />
```

and for what it's worth, the imageUrl does bind correctly, and updates as expected when the Url is changed in the ViewModel. Additionally, the `Debug.PrintLine("Animation triggered")` does print when the cards are created, but never when the property is changed on the ViewModel.

Comment: Have you written a custom binding for `AnimatingColor`? If so, can you post it?

Comment: Because I don't know what you mean when you say that - I expect that might be where my issue is. However, based on the sample from n+1 days, since I'm simply using a string for `AnimatingColor`, I wasn't aware I needed anything more to bind the string to the added property. Edit: Of course, I'm extremely open to the possibility that I'm wrong about how this binding works, I just wanted to make sure I had given as much information as possible.

Comment: Properties that you bind with `local:MvxBind` need to have a [custom binding](http://slodge.blogspot.com/2013/06/n28-custom-bindings-n1-days-of-mvvmcross.html) written for them to do anything. The reason the ImageUrl binding you're using works as expected is because there is a target binding that has been written for it somewhere in MvvmCross itself. If you check your debug output window, is there a message about MvvmCross failing to bind your control for `AnimatingColor`?

Comment: That's what is throwing me off - there isn't any message that I've been able to see. I will run again and go through the output to see, but that was my first thought as well. Edit: there is indeed no binding error for AnimatingColor. It seems to recognize the property and bind the string from the ViewModel appropriately. I will try implementing a custom binding and see what happens.

Comment: Implemented but no change - still no binding error but no animation when the item is pressed. The VM's property is changing, though.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments suggest, I believe you need to create a custom binding for your DynamicImageView control. Something like this should do it:

```
public class DynamicImageViewAnimatingColorBinding : MvxTargetBinding
{
    public DynamicImageViewAnimatingColorBinding(DynamicImageView target) : base(target)
    {
    }

    protected DynamicImageView View => Target as DynamicImageView;

    public override MvxBindingMode DefaultMode => MvxBindingMode.OneWay;

    public override Type TargetType => typeof(string);

    public override void SetValue(object value)
    {
        var view = View;
        if (view == null)
            return;

        view.AnimatingColor = (string) value;
    }
}
```

Then in your Setup class you need to register it so that MvvmCross can use it:

```
protected override void FillTargetFactories(IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.RegisterCustomBindingFactory<DynamicImageView>(
            nameof(DynamicImageView.AnimatingColor),
            image => new DynamicImageViewAnimatingColorBinding (image));

        base.FillTargetFactories(registry);
    }
```

I haven't tested this code and it's based on some very similar code I used on iOS but it should work fine on Android. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Implemented but no change - still no binding error but no animation when the item is pressed. The VM's property is changing, though. I'll keep tinkering around and see what happens.

Comment: Maybe a little basic, but is the page's BindingContext definitely set?

Comment: Hey, just gonna do a facepalm here and apologize for wasting your time. I didn't mention (read: I didn't realize the relevance of) the fact that my CardView is being used as a template in a ListView. The problem is that I was not using an OvservableCollection, so the Property Changes were presumably not percolating through. I have it working now. Thanks for all your help; your clarifying questions absolutely helped me to inspect my code in a more productive way to find the underlying issue. Cheers!

Comment: Glad I was able to help somewhat :)

Comment: I'm happy to see the animation looks great now that it works! Now I want to go and try using a RecyclerView again. It was acting weird with that before, but it's very possible it was because of the issue I discovered there.

Answer (score 0):

James Mundy's questions led me to realize that the underlying issue is that I was not using an ObservableCollection in a list, so the changes to the underlying ViewModels were not being reflected in the UI.